# How to get grandparent of grandchild in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

In Entity Framework, three entities have 1 to many relationships as grandparent, children and grandchildren.

How do you obtain an the grandparent object from a grandchild's primary key?

Thank you,

Newby to EF

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following assuming the grandchildren have a reference (as a DbSet) to their parents, and those have a reference to their parents in return:

```
myGrandChildren.SelectMany(x => x.Parents).SelectMany(x => x.Parents);
```

What `SelectMany` does here is for each grandchildren select all its parents and return them as a single list (instead of as a list of lists - it concats them).

If you just have one grand child - you only need one SelectMany:

```
grandChild.Parents.SelectMany(x => x.Parents);
```

Comment: I am new at EF, so I'm not practiced on how to ask questions. Apologies.

The relationship of grandparent to children, is one to many, and child to granchildren also one to many.  I'm not sure the suggestion gets the response I want, but thank you for introducing me to SelectMany!

Alex

Comment: I'm glad I could help @AlexSosa. For taking a list, getting a list for each item (for example, all the parents of each grandchildren) and returning a list of all the parents concatenated - SelectMany is optimal. It's also called `concatMap` or `flatMap` in other languages - it's a very useful function for these use cases. Don't forget to `.ToList()` or otherwise enumerate it to see the results in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Query to context will be (`grandchildId` it is grandchild's primary key):

```
var grandparent = context
    .Set<GrandParent>()
    .SingleOrDefault(gp => gp.Children.Any(c => c.Children.Any(gc => gc.Id == grandchildId)));
```

if I understand, your classes looks like this:

```
class GrandParent
{
    ...
    public List<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

class Child
{
    ...
    public List<GrandChild> Children {get; set;}
}

class GrandChild
{
    ...
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: My classes are as you assumed.

I didn't get any flags in Visual Studio, but I still don't know how to test it, so I don t know íf it will give the answer expected, but it looks good.

Thank you.